# task within vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to get  code to recreate the words positions within a sentence. For example, the sentence 'This is my project and this is in visual studio' the words position will be recreated such as '1,2,3,4,5,1,2,8,9,10'.

Please can you produce code for this to be possible!

Many thanks

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: At the moment, all it is outputting is the repeated words, however i think i am pretty close.

Comment: I'd say you need to build a list of positions as you find or add words. Then show that list at the end.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Well you need to get the position of the word whether it is new or not: position_list.Add(new_word_list.IndexOf(word) + 1) and then you need to print them out at the end: String.Concat("Your words are in positions ", String.Join(",", position_list.ToArray()))

Comment: Alright, I will try it and feedback, thank you

Comment: For future reference: VBA is for macros in MS Office and is therefore not the same as VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter with LINQ:

```
Dim input = "This is my project and this is in visual studio"

Dim words = Split(input.ToUpper)

Dim indexes = From word In words Select Array.IndexOf(words, word) + 1

Dim result = String.Join(",", indexes)   ' "1,2,3,4,5,1,2,8,9,10"
```